# Problemas com retorno AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_busca_f').click(function () {
            var data_ini = $('#data_ini').val();
            var data_fim = $('#data_fim').val();
            var cod_recurso = $('#cod_recurso').val();
            var cod_funcionario = $('#cod_funcionario').val();
            var num_op = $('#num_op').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                url: '/intranet/ExportaFimApontamento',
                data:{
                    '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                    'data_ini': data_ini, 
                    'data_fim': data_fim, 
                    'cod_recurso': cod_recurso,
                    'cod_funcionario': cod_funcionario,
                    'num_op': num_op
                },
                erro: function () {
                    alert('erro');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    return (data);
                    alert('Excel Gerado com Sucesso!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

este script executa uma função no controller onde ele gera um arquivo excel.xls, porem se eu executar a função direto no controler(sem passar pela pagina) ele funciona, se eu executar com o script(ai em cima) ele funciona mas nao gera o arquivo.xls, ele gera o preview e o response pelo F12 navegador mas nao baixa o excel. alguem sabe como posso fazer para que ele baixe o arquivo ao executar o script?
ou se tem outro metodo? no meu form o submit faz a função porem ele esta la para consultar um relatório.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando tu recebe success no ajax tu já sabe a url de download não?

No laravel tem uma response pra download. veja:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

Depois que receber a resposta de success, tenta dar um:

```
window.location.href = link_para_download
```

Nunca testei assim, mas pode funcionar.